# Passing global variables in .swift to specific viewController

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, global-variables

I want to pass a global array(in `.swift` file) to specific `ViewController`. Here's my code

commonData.swift

```
import Foundation

var regionArray:[Bool]?

let region = [
"United States",
"United Kingdom"
]
```

testTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

var arraySize:Int?
var boolArray:[Bool]?

class testTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.boolArray = regionArray
        self.arraySize = region.count

        if(self.boolArray == nil) {
             self.boolArray = Array(count: self.arraySize!, repeatedValue: false)
             NSLog("Array renewed")
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I tried to enter table view many times, *`regionArray`* in `commonData.swift` prints out "Array renewed" in log data. How can I set and pass a global variable to load/make into specific `viewController`?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you made a typo:

```
class testTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var arraySize:Int?
    var boolArray:[Bool]?
    ...
```

But anyways.

First off. Swift `Arrays` are **not** `objects`, they are `structs` which means you are not passing a reference to an object os by doing:

```
self.boolArray = regionArray
```

You are not passing the reference for `regionArray` to `self.boolArray`, instead whats happening `self.boolArray` is assigned a 'copy' of `regionArray`.

So when you do:

```
self.boolArray = Array(count: self.arraySize!, repeatedValue: false)
```

`regionArray` isnt touched at all you only give `self.boolArray` values.

To fix this you have to change `self.boolArray` with `regionArray` or add:

```
regionArray = self.boolArray
```

Comment: regionArray = self.boolArray is not operated properly on my intention. Call by value was happened I think. I solved this problem by design a singleton pattern variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by designing singleton design pattern. What I've done is

commonData.swift

```
class mySingletonDesign {
     var regionArray:[Bool]?
     let region = [
         "United States",
         "United Kingdom"
     ]
}

var regionInfo = mySingletonDesign()
```

and testTableViewController.swift is

```
import UIKit

class testTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        if(regionInfo.regionArray == nil) {
             regionInfo.regionArray = Array(count: regionInfo.region.count, repeatedValue: false)
             NSLog("Array renewed")
        }
    }
}
```

After this code, "Array renewed" was not called. Because this calling accesses regionInfo variable's direct memory.